# JS floating point causing incorrect rounding - Math.round() always works?

Tags: javascript, floating-point, mat

I have edge cases with floats after multiplying.

I have to round numbers to the nearest hundred, but in cases like that:

`115000*4.35 //500249.99999999994`

I'll get a wrong result:

```
Math.round(115000*4.35 / 100) * 100 //500200
```

instead of `500300`

A solution:

First rounding to the nearest one decimal place:

```
  Math.round(500249.99999999994 * 10) / 10 //200250,
```

then rounding to the nearest hundred:

```
Math.round(500250 / 100) * 100 //200300
```

combined:

```
Math.round(Math.round(num * 10) / 1000) * 100
```

Does anyone know if it's a safe way to solve it? Does it always work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your combined solution returns 1 less zero, needs * 100 not * 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does anyone know if it's a safe way to solve it? Does it always work?

It is not safe and does not always work.

Consider 100,005 • 9.99. In real arithmetic, this is 999,049.95, and you apparently desire to round it to the nearest multiple of 100, producing 999,000.

9.99 cannot be stored in a JavaScript Number. The nearest representable value is 9.9900000000000002131628207280300557613372802734375. Multiplying this by 100.005 in JavaScript’s floating-point arithmetic yields 999,049.950000000069849193096160888671875.

Your proposed solution first attempts to round that to the nearest multiple of 1/10. In this case, it succeeds, yielding 999,050. (In many cases, this fails, since the only multiples of 1/10 that can be represented are those that are multiples of 5/10.) Then using `Math.round(999050 / 100) * 100)` yields 999,100 (since `Math.round` rounds halfway cases upward).

Even if real arithmetic were used, rather than floating-point arithmetic, your proposed solution would not work. Rounding 999,049.95 to the nearest multiple of 1/10 using the same method (halfway cases up) yields 999,050, and rounding that to the nearest multiple of 100 yields 999,100.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Any idea to improve it/solution without using libs? thanks!

Comment: @Esther-I: In the IEEE-754 binary64 format JavaScript uses, 4.35 cannot be represented. The closest representable number is 4.3499999999999996447286321199499070644378662109375. Thus, in attempting to round `115000*4.35`, you have already lost information. The evaluated product is 500249.9999999999417923390865325927734375. Any function you pass this to receives only that number, and there is no way for it to know that you desired 500250 instead. So no rounding function such as you desire is possible with only this situation.

Comment: @Esther-I: The problem can be solved only by providing additional information to the function, possibly by passing it in other arguments, or possibly building it into the function. For example, if **all** inputs to the function are known to be the floating-point product of an integer and a floating-point number that is closest to some multiple of .01, then it might be possible to design a function that does what you want. (Indeed, stated that way, multiplying by 100 instead of 10 for the initial rounding is a potential approach, as long as the product is not so large additional errors occur.)

Comment: Thanks so much for your explanation!  What do you mean "only by providing additional information to the function, possibly by passing it in other arguments, or possibly building it into the function"? thanks again!

Comment: Eric, Do you think that multiplying by 100 instead of 10 for the initial rounding is a good approach? thanks.

Comment: @Esther-I: Providing additional information to the function means it uses some information other than the single number passed to it as an argument. It needs to have something else, such as knowledge that the number passed to it is the result of converting a decimal numeral with at most two digits after the decimal point to JavaScript’s `Number` format and then multiplying it by an integer, and that some limit on the magnitude is satisfied. Since the problem is not solvable in general for any `Number` value, there must be some restriction on the values.

Comment: @Esther-I: I cannot say whether an initial multiplication by 100 and rounding will solve the problem. You need to add additional information to the problem. Your example shows `115000*4.35`. Will **every** instance in which this rounding is desired be a situation in which an integer (like 115000) is multiplied by a number that came from a decimal numeral with at most two digits after the decimal point (like 4.35)? If not, what are the other uses cases? How big can the integer be? How big can the second number be? Where do these numbers come from? Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: "Will every instance in which this rounding is desired be a situation in which an integer (like 115000) is multiplied by a number that came from a decimal numeral with at most two digits after the decimal point (like 4.35)?" **Yes**. "How big can the integer be?" **about 6 digits**."How big can the second number be?" **Not big**. "Where do these numbers come from?" **From Excel**. Thanks so nuch!

Comment: @Esther-I: Enter a new question with the necessary information. Example: “Real numbers *a* and *b*, with *a* an integer with 0 ≤ *a* < 10^6 and b a multiple of .01 with 0 ≤ *b* < 10^6 are converted to JavaScript Numbers `a` and `b` and multiplied to produce `c`. How can I implement a function to round `c` to the multiple of 100 nearest to *c* = *ab*, with ties rounded upward? For example, with *a* = 115000 and *c* 435, `c` is 500249.9999999999417923390865325927734375, but *c* would be 500,250, and I want the function to return 500,300.”

Comment: @Esther-I: With the example above, converting *a* to `Number` has no error, converting *b* has an error of at most 2^(19-53), and the computed `c` differs from *c* by at most 10^6•2^(19-53) + 2^-53•10^12 plus a tiny bit more, and that is about .00017. All the possible values for *c* differ by at least .01 (because all *a* values differ by at least 1 and all *b* values differ by at least .01, so all *ab* values differ by at least 1•.01 = .01). Therefore, 100 *ab* is an integer, and, if we round `a*b*100` to an integer, the accumulated errors are so small that we must get the same number.

Comment: @Esther-I: I did some informal error analysis in there, but, if it holds up, it means that `Math.round(a*b*100)` produces exactly the value of 100 *ab*. Then it is safe to divide for rounding (because the edge case has the fraction 50/100, which is representable in the `Number` format, so there is no arithmetic error), so `Math.round(Math.round(a*b*100)/10000)*100` should work.

Comment: @Esther-I: Note that, for the preliminary rounding, any quantum between the *ab* quantum (.01) and the known error bound (around .00017) can be used. For example, 1/128 would be fine, and using a power of two avoids introducing any more rounding errors. So we could use `Math.round(Math.round(a*b*128) / (128*100)) * 100`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Eric Postpischil! It was very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Rounding to the nearest integer can be simply done by calling

```
Math.round(500249.99999999994)
```

So rounding to the nearest hundred becomes:

```js
const num = 115000*4.35;

const roundedToNearestHundred = Math.round(Math.round(num) / 100) * 100;

console.log(roundedToNearestHundred);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but for such a case: `Math.round(Math.round(500249.8) / 100) * 100` will be returned `500300` instead of `500200`, so it doesn't work.